# why am i getting these errors "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined " and "Uncaught Error: No module: kendo.directives "?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-asp.net-mvc

when i am running my code it is showing nothing and in the console of browser i am getting these two errors-
1. "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined " and
2. "Uncaught Error: No module: kendo.directives " i don't know what wrong is going on in there.

My code is -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angularjs.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-kendo.js"></script>

<script>
    var myModule = angular.module('myApp', ["kendo.directives"]);
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-kendo data-role="calendar"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if Angular Kendo depends on UnderscoreJS which you have not included. That's your first error, but because of it the `'kendo.directives'` module never gets created.

Download [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) and include it before your Kendo scripts.

Comment: thank you for your answer it worked, now it is not giving any error but it is not showing any widget. now what is the problem?

Comment: Hard to say without more info. Create a fiddle/plunker and it will be easier to help (perhaps it should be a new question?).

Comment: i have also posted one separate question for it and a new fiddle too. here is the link- http://jsfiddle.net/akki166786/MYe2T/